# No change after committing in git

Tags: eclipse, git

When I check out a project from git, many files need to commit, but nothing changes, can anybody tell me why ?

[image]

I just checked out from git, doing nothing, I am sure it's not the text encoding thing

Comment: I'm not too familiar with git in eclipse, but I would check the project with external git tools, with which you can look exactly what is happening. This screenshot doesn't really contain much information.

Comment: I checked out using Git Bash, when I import to eclipse, also have the same problem

Comment: Use git bash to see what's the problem, not to clone the project. After cloning see what `git status` returns

Comment: if my answer is wrong, it may be some automatic thing done by eclipse related to end of line / end of file transformation.

Comment: I have got the answer, the reason is the line delimiter of the eclipse, its default is Unix, when I changed to Windows, everything is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer, the reason is the line delimiter of the eclipse, its default is Unix, when I changed to Windows, everything is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Differences may be related to file execution permissions. If so, `git diff` will give you the old chmod/current chmod. To restore it to the correct permissions, you can do `git checkout .` or `git reset --hard`.

Other solution if you simply don't care about files permission, you can tell git to ignore it by editing `.git/config.php` or by typing from the root directory `git config core.fileMode false`